# how to express multiple relation query by queryBuilder

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typeorm

there are my database tables:

#### device table:

+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
|                          device                         |
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
| device_id          | int(11)      | PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT |
| device_name        | varchar(255) |                            |
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+

#### user table：

+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
|                          user                         |
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
| user_id          | int(11)      | PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT |
| user_name        | varchar(255) |                            |
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+

#### device-user-association table

+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
|                          device_administrators                         |
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
| id          | int(11)      | PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT |
| device_id        | int(11) |                            |
| user_id        | int(11) |                            |
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
question 1 :how to construct the entity?
question 2 :how to express multiple relation query by queryBuilder and Map result as follows?

```json
{
    "device_id":1,
    "device_name":"projector",
    "deviceAdmins":[
        {
            "user_id":1,
            "user_name":"Tom",
        },
        {
            "user_id":2,
            "user_name":"Marry"
        }
    ]
}
```

maybe I am terrible in database table design

I have no idear and found nothing in Example;
Maybe the table design is terrible then I should change the relation design